# What is meant by "polynomial in $x$ and $y$ (poly($x$,$y$))"?

Tags: polynomials, notation, terminology

Is it only terms that are sums of poly($x$) and poly($y$)? or can it include terms such as $xy, (xy)^2$ etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial in $x$ and $y$ is a finite sum of terms that are of the shape $cx^my^n$ for non-negative integers $m,n$ and values of $c$ appropriate to the context (any real number in many cases).

$xy\ (=1x^1y^1)$ is a valid term, as is $(xy)^2\ (=1x^2y^2)$.